# Studio lighting: Is strobe the same as triggered flash?

Tags: lighting, studio

Considering purchasing the Einstein E640.  Employee at Camera Company wasn't sure if thats the same as strobe lighting

Comment: There can be quite a difference between different studio strobes and especially speedlites when it comes to flash duration, which is well explained here: http://www.paulcbuff.com/sfe-flashduration.php

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Einstein E640 is a studio strobe or studio flash. They are really the same thing.

Here is a link to the User Manual: [Einstein E640 Flash Unit User manual](http://www.paulcbuff.com/manuals/e640.pdf)